# Creating Python callback via monkey-patching

Tags: python, callback, monkeypatching

I'm creating an object that will represent some system info that can be changed outside of my program.  Im thinking about allowing a callback function to be specified by the user of my code that will be called when a change is detected.  This is what I have, which seems to work (the function `doodie` would be user supplied)

```
def doodie(cls):
    print cls.teststr

class Testarino(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.teststr = 'Yay!'

    def callback(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def go(self):
         self.callback(self)

 tester = Testarino()
 tester.callback = doodie

 tester.go()
```

I thought about using a user supplied decorator, but I think that might be less intuitive for a user.

Is this the best way to do this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for monkey-patching here, it would be cleaner to add a `set_callback()` function to your `Testarino` class, like this:

```
def doodie(cls):
    print cls.teststr

class Testarino(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.teststr = 'Yay!'
        self.callback = None

    def set_callback(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def go(self):
         if self.callback is None:
             raise NotImplementedError
         self.callback(self)

tester = Testarino()
tester.set_callback(doodie)

tester.go()
```

Comment: I had a feeling I was over-complicating it

Comment: @tMC - A common problem in software development!

Comment: The difference between this and the original is *precisely* the the general difference between a "public" member variable or a "private" member variable with a setter method. The fact that it's callable doesn't really make a difference. If you generally prefer setters to just documenting the variable as part of your public interface, F.J's answer is the way to go, otherwise the original is fine. Personally I think the setter is *more* complicated, not less, but that's just a matter of taste, really.